# How do I implement a method with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: f#, paramarray

How do I implement a method with a variable number of arguments?

[In C#, we can use the params keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
 }
```

So how can I do this in F#?

```
type MyClass() =

    member this.SomeMethod(params (args:string array)) = ()
```

I receive the following error from the code above:

```
The pattern discriminator 'params' is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In F#, how do you curry ParamArray functions (like sprintf)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145680/in-f-how-do-you-curry-paramarray-functions-like-sprintf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`ParamArrayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx):

```
type MyClass() =
    member this.SomeMethod([<ParamArray>] (args:string array)) = Array.iter (printfn "%s") args
```

then:

```
let mc = MyClass()
mc.SomeMethod("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: How to pass the array at once?