# How to wrap printfn in F#?

Tags: f#

I have read about continuations and partial applications; I am also aware of the kprintf function.

But I still don't know how to write something like:

```
let myPrintFunction format variable_length_arguments_list =
    let a = sprintf format variable_length_ argument_list
    do other things
```

what would be the syntax this this?

so I could use it like:

```
myPrintFunction "%s : %i" "hello" 3
```

---

Edit:

This is different than [How do I implement a method with a variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696008/how-do-i-implement-a-method-with-a-variable-number-of-arguments) because that question is asking how to make a method with a variable number of arguments, but the issue I am facing is to pass that variable number of argument to the next function (sprintf) that takes a variable number of arguments too.
Or, at least that's where I suppose the problem is.

The test code, based on the solution proposed by Scott can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCzcS9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement a method with a variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696008/how-do-i-implement-a-method-with-a-variable-number-of-arguments)

Comment: No, the F# format system does not exist in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to demonstrate the ksprintf function, because that one accepts a continuation that will allow you to pass on the resulting string to e.g. a log system.

For the purpose of demonstration, let's first create something that can take a single string as input and pass it on, in this case to the console.

```
let writeStringToConsole (s: string) = Console.WriteLine ("OUTPUT : " + s)
```

So now, if writeStringToConsole is all we have, how to we make it accept F# formatting?

```
let printToConsole format = Printf.ksprintf writeStringToConsole format
```

Example that demonstrates that it works.

```
type DU = A | B
let i = 7
let s = "thirteen"
let du = B

printToConsole """an int %i and a string "%s" here""" i s
printToConsole """an int %i and a string "%s" and DU %A here""" i s du

// OUTPUT : an int 7 and a string "thirteen" here
// OUTPUT : an int 7 and a string "thirteen" and DU B here

// Note that OUTPUT is also part of the actual output,
// and it demonstrates how you can add e.g. a timestamp
// or line number or something to the output string, without
// it being part of the formatting.
```

edit: Some additional notes

The format string must be a literal. That's because the literal string must be read at compile time in order to compute the function that must be returned in order to gobble up whatever values/types that follow the format string.

For example, if you do `printToConsole "%i %s %A %A" 7 "x" myType yourType`, then you'll see `int -> string -> MyType -> YourType` in the signature of `printToConsole` where it's used.

There is a way to use plain strings as format strings with this system, but I don't remember how it's done, and anyway it spoils the type safety. It comes in handy when doing internationalization of strings, and your format strings must come from a resource and not F# source due to external translator services.

edit 2 : Wrap e.g. log system

I created an interface to use for various logging systems, which pretty much share the same features.

```
type ILogger =
```

...

```
    abstract member Debugf: StringFormat<'h, unit> -> 'h
    abstract member Verbosef: StringFormat<'h, unit> -> 'h
    abstract member Infof: StringFormat<'h, unit> -> 'h
    abstract member Warningf: StringFormat<'h, unit> -> 'h
    abstract member Errorf: StringFormat<'h, unit> -> 'h
    abstract member Fatalf: StringFormat<'h, unit> -> 'h
```

Then an implementation for my currently used logging system looks like this.

```
type internal SiLogger(session: Session) =
    let slogf = Printf.ksprintf
```

...

```
    interface ILogger with
```

...

```
    member _.Debugf format = slogf session.LogDebug format
    member _.Verbosef format = slogf session.LogVerbose format
    member _.Infof format = slogf session.LogMessage format
    member _.Warningf format = slogf session.LogWarning format
    member _.Errorf format = slogf session.LogError format
    member _.Fatalf format = slogf session.LogFatal format
```

And there is a null logger.

```
let slogf = Printf.ksprintf

let dummyLog _ = () // The parameter is the title string.

let dummy format = slogf dummyLog format

let getNullLogger () =
    { new ILogger with
```

...

```
        member _.Debugf format = dummy format
        member _.Verbosef format = dummy format
        member _.Infof format = dummy format
        member _.Warningf format = dummy format
        member _.Errorf format = dummy format
        member _.Fatalf format = dummy format
```

...

```
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to know how many arguments 'format' has? I'm wondering if it's possible to detect printToConsole "hello" as a single argument and print the string as it, alleviating the need for printToConsole "%s" "hello"

Comment: As a side note if your doing this to do logging in a production service there's more to it then that and other requirements will come up. I would consider the use of an F# logging library for this. I had to write LoggerWrapper.FSharp to make logging functions that do the things your probably looking for as you go down the rabbit hole. e.g if logging is disabled it shouldn't attempt to build the string/allocate memory for performance reasons - which is usually true for debug logging. kprintf does this without wrapping the whole thing up and therefore it can get tricky to implement.

Comment: I suspect the null logger that I've now added to the answer will do work that isn't needed. That could be an advantage if you want the load during debugging, but you could also I guess add something like `if enabled then dummy format`. Or just not use ksprintf at all in the null logger.

Comment: Oh, and I also have members Debug, Verbose, etc, that just plain outputs a string without using formatting. For performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
open System

let myPrintFunction (format: Printf.StringFormat<_>) ([<ParamArray>] args) =
    let a = sprintf format args
    a

myPrintFunction "%s : %i" "hello" 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to know the number of arguments in 'args'?

Comment: actually it doesn't work when called from a class:   [FS0003] This value is not a function and cannot be applied. With the code being:         let Print (format: Printf.StringFormat<_>) ([<ParamArray>] args) = \n
            let message = sprintf format args \n
            ConsoleInfoEvent.Trigger message \n
            printfn "%s" message

Comment: and the call being:  Print "%s : %i" "hello" 3

Comment: So you want myPrintFunction to be a member function of a class?

Comment: yes; I don't understand why the code would be different though?

Comment: That fiddle link did not seem to arrive at the correct code.

Comment: Make sure your main function returns an int like 0. This answer works as is, but not if you attempt to add a side effect like a `printfn` call.

Comment: what this function is supposed to do is take parameters, like a printfn, generate a string with sprintf, call an event and print out the result. I have seen similar code online with kprintf, but I didn't quite understand how kprintf works

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand kprintf better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570101/5652483

Comment: This compiles and works without the type annotations in F# 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

To add the PrintF as a member function, this is the closest I could get. As you see, I had to pass the format string separately (in the constructor, or I could have used a property setter). I could find no way to pass the format string as the first parameter of the PrintF function as I could for a free function (see my other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58822618/5652483).

Also, if I uncomment the line `this.RaiseSomeEvent msg`, then it breaks. So I could find no way to enable the PrintF function to have a side effect.

Hopefully, someone else can solve these issues.

```
type Foo (format: Printf.StringFormat<_>) =
    member this.RaiseSomeEvent msg = printf "%s" msg

    member this.PrintF ([<ParamArray>] args) =
        let msg = sprintf format args
        //this.RaiseSomeEvent msg
        msg

let foo = Foo("%s : %i")
foo.PrintF "hello" 3
```